# What advantages does windows 8 offer a laptop user (without a touch screen) over windows7?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I am not trying to start a flame war here, I would like a list of valid reasons for updating a traditional, **non tactile** laptop from windows 7 to windows 8.

Apart from faster booting and touch functionality (if your hardware can take advantage of it) I cannot see any reason why one would *want* to upgrade to this new OS.

---

UPDATE

OK, downvotes and close votes already. I do not want to open a discussion, I just want some concrete reasons why windows 8 is better than windows 7.

Comment: @TaylorGibb, reposted as a question, care to comment?

Comment: Presumably there are some features other than touch included... http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/meet

Comment: This still sounds like the kind of question that this site tries avoid. ie. it's too open ended and prone to flame wars,

Comment: @Jikag yeah, I tried to edit it away from that. Should be better now. I am just looking for some specific areas (excluding touchscreens) where windows 8 is better than 7.

Comment: Hyper-V and Windows-To-Go (Enterprise version), would be a few I can think of, even though I have no plans of upgrading to Win8 from Win7. Or Internet Explorer 10? lol I'm writing this all with a bit of sarcasm. Although other OSes could do the Bootable OS on a USB for awhile, the Windows To Go seems pretty cool.

Comment: @j_bombay, I am not a MS fanboy, but I do like using IE10 for testing purposes.  I have to test many scenarios, and it was nice of MS to finally have a browser that was somewhat standards compliant.

Comment: @DaBaer is it really? I did not know that, that's great news.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_8

Comment: Sorry, but this question is asking everyone to post their opinion. You can look up features of Windows 8 online, and I'm sure there have been countless reviews as well. We expect questions to be based on an actual problem, but this is really just polling for opinions. It'd be a great discussion for [chat] though.

Comment: @slhck OK, fair enough, I was hoping someone would just give an actual list of the things MS have improved. Oh well, fell free to close it then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, my favorite changes are the improved task manger, a small speed boost, faster bootup and the new  "corners" interface. It doesn't really feel like that large of a difference between 7 and 8.

If you want a full list of features, you can go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_8 and see if anything catches your eye.

Comment: Sweet, that list is exactly what I was looking for. For some reason I did not stumble upon it when googling.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that with my power settings set to always on, I have about 40% more life on the same laptop when running in Windows 8 over my Windows 7 install. I went as far as doing time tests on battery life while surfing the web and writing some code, and popped back in the old Win 7 drive and confirmed the battery life difference.

Comment: Ah, OK, that's a good one.

Comment: But keeping in mind, this could also be specific to my hardware, but I have heard from others that they see similar response.  I am running a Toshiba L775D

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, there is no reason to switch to windows 8 if you are not doing it for the new interface and windows 8 app store.

Being a developer myself my requirements are less fancy then a "normal" user. I need a system to be stable. And windows 7 does that job fine.

I do guess that the new windows 8 app store might be a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 is essentially Windows 7 with the addition of a tiled start screen (it was primarily developed for use with tablet touchscreens as opposed to desktops). If you want to learn all that the tiled start screen has to offer (and there is a lot to learn) it may well prepare you for future versions of Windows in years to come. If you don't then do not upgrade to Windows 8, stick with Windows 7